# How to capture audio on c++ UWP app with WASAPI?

Tags: c++, audio, uwp, audio-recording, wasapi

I can not seem to find any tutorial on the internet for my question.
All [the simple guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession) is not suitable for UWP.

For Example,
To use WASAPI there are these steps

- enumerate devices
- capture audio
- play (render) audio back

But the enumerating step, The client must call [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686615). But from my understanding this function [is not support in UWP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/347262de-7d9a-42f9-baa3-218e1413d741/uwpc-a-serious-bug-wack-failure-cocreateinstance-not-supported?forum=wpdevelop). Also I failed at Line 30 when following [this code](https://github.com/meitooth/my/blob/288e4f69d333926848026782cacda35a0953d6f4/OBS_0_60b_SourcePs/Source/GetAudioDevices.cpp).

So, I try to understand This, [C++ UWP using WASAPI](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession), But I can't find any Enumerate part and this project is very complicate for me.
It include a lot of other files (DeviceState.h, common.h)

And I failed to extract the code to create my own application.

My question is how can I capture audio on c++ UWP app with WASAPI?

**If this question is too board, I will change my question to How to enumerate audio device in c++ UWP application?.**

And the reason why I use WASAPI is because I want to access the data stored in the Buffer.

Edit:
For enumerating.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/7c7832e1f144e4fc836603fd70e1352024a5fe1a/Samples/WindowsAudioSession/cpp/Scenario1.xaml.cpp#L85

Comment: Are you sure CoCreateInstance is required for the enumeration in the first sample you have referenced? It looks like it is only using UWP compatible functions.

Comment: It is not clear you want to capture the audio from a capture device (microphone line-in) or if you want to capture the audio from a render device (speakers...) the later is called WASAPI loopback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm working on your guide line.
I want to capture from the microphone. And about CoCreateInstance I honestly not sure at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use WASAPI to do audio capturing in UWP and this is what is done in the sample you have referenced (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession).

For the enumeration, the main function is `DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync` with this selector `MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector` it will allow you to list the capture devices.

For the stream capturing, the main function you need is
`ActivateAudioInterfaceAsync`, it will allow you to create an `IAudioClient` from a device id (specific device) or a device class (render or capture) if you just need to use the default device.
Once you have this `IAudioClient` you can use it to get an `IAudioClientCapture`, basically the things that you have seen in the sample.